# Adding <hr/> using the :after selector

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to "automatically" add a horizontal-rule after each article in my page. Is there a way of doing this using the :after selector? I'm hoping to be able to style it something like this:

```
article {
    padding: 10px;
}

article:after {
    content: <hr/>;
}
```

Comment: you can't with pure CSS

Comment: Because of security reasons you are not allowed to add html tags to the content attribute.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is impossible with pure CSS, but you could use a border and margins to look like a `hr`:

```
article {
    margin: 3px 0px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Or you could use JavaScript:

```
var articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article')
for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i ++) {
    articles[i].parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('hr'), articles[i].nextSibling)
}
```

Or easier in jQuery:

```
$('article').after('<hr/>')
```

Answer (score 23):

CSS only solution

```
article {
    position: relative;
}

article:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px; /* suit your need */
    background: black; /* suit your need */
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: `display: block` seems to be required also.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an older question, but considering there aren't yet any correct CSS-only answers (although Bobby was close), I'll add my two cents.

You cannot use CSS to add HTML tags to a page. However, there is a CSS-only solution to achieve the same visual effect.

You can use the `::after` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter)  to do this. This creates an element after the specified element, in this case the `article`.

Using `content: ''` gives an empty element, which we then style to fit the whole width of the screen (`width:100vw`), with a `height` of our choice (in this case only `1px`) and we give it a `background-color` in order to make it visible as a line. Using `position:absolute` and `left:0` ensures the line will always stick to the left side of the screen, and because it is as wide as the screen, it will always span the entire width.

If you don't want the line spanning the entire screen, you can use `100%` instead of `100vw` to make it span accross whatever element you put it inside. (That would be the `article` element's parent in this example).

```
article {
    position: relative;
}

article::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot with pure CSS/HTML. You would need some sort of scripting such as Javascript to handle the logic.

Using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("article").after("<hr>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
yourclass:before {  
    content: "";
    border-left: 2px solid green;
    height: 28px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or this, for a similar result:

```
article:after{
    content :"";
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
}
```