# AddToAny: Add a horizontal line between post and sharing buttons

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using WordPress with twenty fourteen theme. I installed the plugin AddToAny for adding a floating bar and sharing buttons after every post. So far everything is working well.

But I would like to add a horizontal line between the end of the post and the sharing buttons. I guess I have to fix it via CSS, but unfortunately I don't have any clue how to do it.

Comment: I expect a WordPress freelancer could do this for you at a minimal cost. There are plenty of freelancing websites, maybe try those? If you want to do this at no cost, or with volunteer help, you will need to do some research first, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using code, you could append a horizontal line to the content and do something like this with a filter:

```
function my_after_content($content) {
   $content  .=  '<hr>';

   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_after_content');
```

But you would be better off if  you just added a border under an element using css. You could also insert an

---

using javascript.

This similar question has a css example and also provides a javascript solution and a pretty straightforward jquery solution that I like a lot:

[Adding <hr/> using the :after selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736211/adding-hr-using-the-after-selector)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Oh my goodness, I have no idea where to put this code.

Comment: Normally after my post there are the flags of the categories. That looks pretty good. But now the sharing buttons of AddToAny are inserted between text and categories. I would like to put the sharing buttons after the categories and afterwards add a line. You know what I mean? Do you know how to replace the buttons?

Comment: Is this because you added the border? Check the settings of your share buttons - you should be able to change it in the settings or you can try a different plugin.   I would agree with the person above - what you want to do is pretty simple and it wouldn't cost you too much money to hire them.